# PHP date year format

Tags: php

I am having problems with dates in php- sometimes the date gets to us in d/m/y and other times its d/m/Y. I want to convert all dates to d/m/Y.

Working with my current dataset, how would I get 24/06/2015 from 24/06/15 using php?

So far I have tried :

```
$original_date = '24/06/15';

$new_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($original_date));
```

This brings back 01/01/1970

Comment: $date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($original));

Comment: Maybe [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is what you are looking for?

Comment: please fix a) your task or b) your example. the task described doesn't state `Y-=1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the most robust method:

```
$string = '24/06/15';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $string) ?: DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $string);
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

`createFromFormat` returns `false` if you try to parse 24/06/2014 using the d/m/y format, so in that case you just retry with d/m/Y. You then get a `DateTime` object which you can format and output any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

use the lowercase 'y'. See the PHP date [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$new_date = date('d/m/y', strtotime($original_date));
```

> y =   A two digit representation of a year

Comment: I didnt down vote but I think its because Ive asked for Y

Comment: the "date('d/m/y', strtotime($original_date));" part should work. yeah?

Comment: This will just output "01/01/70" instead of "01/01/1970". Hardly any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the strtotime doesn't recognise the UK date format, so convert the format first then format the date.

Try this:

```
$original_date = "24/06/15"; 
list($date,$month,$year) = sscanf($original_date, "%d/%d/%d");
$date_convert = $year."-".$month."-".$date;
$new_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date_convert));
echo $new_date;
```

Answer (score -1):

Its wrong format of date you are using for `strtotime`.

Have a look at [Date Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

The correct code should have

```
$original_date = '15/06/24'; // Notice : its mm/dd/yy here

$new_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($original_date));
```